# JNA call works with 32-bit JRE but not with 64-bit JRE

Tags: jvm, java, jna

I am trying to call *system32*'s *CreateProcessW* from my JNA interface that I have created. The problem is that it works fine when I am running the software from a 32-bit JRE but when I move over to a 64-bit JRE it crashes the JVM.

```
Kernel32 kernel = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32",
        Kernel32.class, new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            {
                put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER,
                        W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
                put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER,
                        W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
            }
        });

ProcessInformation processInformation = new ProcessInformation();
byte[] startupInfo = new byte[67];

int num2 = BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, 60);
int num = BitConverter.toInt16(bytes, num2 + 6);
IntByReference ptr4 = new IntByReference(BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, num2 + 0x54));
kernel.CreateProcessW(surrogateProcess, null, 0, 0, false, 4, 0,
            null, startupInfo, processInformation);
```

My *Kernel32* JNA interface:

```
public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    boolean CreateProcessW(String appName, String commandLine, int procAttr,
        int thrAttr, boolean inherit, int creation, int env, String curDir,
        byte[] sInfo, ProcessInformation pInfo);

}
```

My *ProcessInformation* JNA structure:

```
public final class ProcessInformation extends Structure implements ByReference {

    public IntByReference hProcess;
    public IntByReference hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays
                .asList("hProcess", "hThread", "dwProcessId", "dwThreadId");
    }

}
```

Finally, here is the error that occurs when I run on a 64-bit JRE:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077a4e711, pid=1888, tid=8968
#
# JRE version: 6.0_43-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x4e711]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Thomas\workspace\trident\hs_err_pid1888.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mapping is bogus.  Where did you get the idea you could use Java `int` to represent pointer values?  Oh, never mind, the win32 API must have taught you that.

You must use `Pointer` or `PointerType` or an equivalent to represent pointers, or if you're *really* stuck on using integer values, at least use `long` (64 bits) on a 64-bit platform.

BTW, JNA includes a `platform.jar` that includes kernel32 mappings, including `CreateProcess`.